# Stack Pandas dataframe with column headers

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe

```
   Date   Brand    Value_A    Value_B    Metric_A   Metric_b
1   xx      dd      1          6           A          d
2   xx      dd      2          5           A          D
3   zxx     d       3          6           A          f
```

and I wanted to transform two this:

```
    Date   Brand     Value     Metric
1     xx    dd        1           A     
2     xx    dd        2           A
3     zxx   d         3           A
4     xx    dd        6           d
5     xx    d         5           D
6     zxx   dd        6           f
```

I don't think melt will work with this type of problem as I have to column headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 separate Dataframes, rename columns and concat

```
df1 = df[['Date','Brand','Value_A','Metric_A']]
df2 = df[['Date','Brand','Value_B','Metric_B']]

coluns = ['Date','Brand','Value','Metric']

df1.columns = coluns
df2.columns = coluns

df_full = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a `wide_to_long` problem

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['Value','Metric'],
                i=['Date','Brand','index'],
                j='drop',sep='_',suffix='\w+').\
        reset_index(level=[0,1])
Out[748]: 
           Date Brand  Value Metric
index drop                         
1     A      xx    dd      1      A
      B      xx    dd      6      d
2     A      xx    dd      2      A
      B      xx    dd      5      D
3     A     zxx     d      3      A
      B     zxx     d      6      f
```